# Meteor js displaying result from method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I do have a template and i'm trying to display a variable which should be modified from a method

Heres how my code looks like

The html

```
{{test}}
```

The server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        callApi: function (term) {
            this.unblock();
            try {
                const result = HTTP.call('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search')
                return result;
            } catch (e) {
                // Got a network error, timeout, or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
                console.log(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The client

```
    Template.body.helpers({
        test: 'test'
    });
Template.body.events({
        'submit .media-Search'(event, template) {
            // Prevent default browser form submit
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get value from form element
            const target = event.target;
            const text = target.text.value;

            Meteor.call("callApi", text, function(error, results) {
                if (error)
                    console.log(error);

                template.test = results.data.items[0].snippet.channelId; //results.data should be a JSON object
            });

            // Clear form
            target.text.value = '';
        },
    });
```

The variable does change but the change is not shown on the html page, What am i doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to store your Meteor method result in a reactive variable / reactive dictionary:

```
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

Template.body.onCreated(function() {
    this.test = new ReactiveVar(); // create reactive var

})
```

Later in your submit event:

```
// ...
Meteor.call("callApi", text, function(error, results) {
    if (error) console.log(error);

    // set value for reactive variable
    template.test.set(results.data.items[0].snippet.channelId);
});
```

Your template helper is currently a string (I wonder that the build system does not throw an Error on this) but should be a method that returns your updated reactive variable:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    test() {
        return Template.instance().test.get();
    }
});
```

You should read some more on Blaze and ReactiveVar documentation:

http://blazejs.org/

https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html